# Help about WiFi routers

Tags: wireless

I want to ask that I am having useless CDMA fixed wireless terminal(model LST 260t). Can this be used as wireless router for my computer. If yes how can I use.

Answer (score 0):

From the device's user manual:

> This CDMA digital technology has greatly enhanced voice clarity and
>   can provide various advanced features. **The terminal enables the normal
>   operation and direct connection of standard telephone equipment into
>   the cellular network**.
>
> The standard unit provides:
>
> - **A phone jack to plug in the telephone equipment(RJ-11 Port)**
> - Ring voltage used to ring the telephone connected to the unit, with a Ringer Equivalence Number of 4
> - A phone jack to plug in the G3 FAX equipment (RJ-11 Port)
> - Data Port for service and repair(RJ-45 Port or USB Port)
> - AC Power supply with barrel plug connector
> - Support Dial tone
> - Touch tone(DTMF) or Pulse Dialing
> - Support Caller ID Telephone
> - Voice-Mail Notification ring alerts you to new voice-mail messages
> - Three lights (LEDs) to indicate the status of the unit
> - Dipole Antenna

So no, you won't be able to use this device as a wireless router.